# Ideas on javascript pagination

Tags: javascript, mysql, xml, pagination

I'm developing a google map with populated data from a mysql database using an .xml file to transfer the data between. On the same page as the map I have a table displaying all the data from the .xml file. Now I need to know how I can paginate them using javascript.

Here is my code:

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

      var side_bar_html = '<tr class="style19"><td width="12%" height="51" class="table-header-repeat line-left"><p><a href="">Business Name</a></p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p></td>Address<td width="17%"class="table-header-repeat line-left" bgcolor="#EEEEEE"><p><a href="">Address</a></td><td width="14%"class="table-header-repeat line-left" bgcolor="#EEEEEE"><p><a href="">Licence Type</a></td><td width="9%" class="table-header-repeat line-left" bgcolor="#EEEEEE"><p><a href="">LicenceNumber</a></td><td width="9%"class="table-header-repeat line-left" bgcolor="#EEEEEE"><p><a href="">Phone</a></td><td width="12%"class="table-header-repeat line-left" bgcolor="#EEEEEE"><p><a href="">Locate</a></td></tr>'; 
      var to_htmls = [];
      var from_htmls = [];
      var htmls = [];
      var gmarkers = []; 
      var marker = new GMarker(point);
      var i = gmarkers.length;
      var map = null;
      var contentString = html;
function downloadUrl(url,callback) 
{
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
      new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
      new XMLHttpRequest;

         request.onreadystatechange = function() {
     if (request.readyState == 4) 
     {
         request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
         callback(request, request.status);
   }
};

         request.open('GET', url, true);
         request.send(null);
}
     gmarkers.push(marker);
     //side_bar_html += '<a href="javascript:myclick(' + (gmarkers.length-1) + ')">' + name + '<\/a><br>';

     side_bar_html += '<tr><tr class="style40"><td height="39" nowrap="nowrap" bgcolor="#EEEEEE"><span class="style17">' + name + '</span></td><td height="39" nowrap="nowrap" bgcolor="#EEEEEE"><span class="style17">'+address+'</span></td><td height="39" nowrap="nowrap" bgcolor="#EEEEEE"><span class="style17"> '+ type +'</span></td><td height="39" nowrap="nowrap" bgcolor="#EEEEEE"><span class="style17">'+ licence_number +'</span></td><td height="39" nowrap="nowrap" bgcolor="#EEEEEE"><span class="style17">'+ phone +'</span></td><td height="39" nowrap="nowrap" bgcolor="#EEEEEE"><span class="style17"><a href="javascript:myclick(' + (gmarkers.length-1) + ')">Locate<\/a><br></span></td></tr>';

function myclick(i)
 {
     google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[i], "click");
        function myclick(i) { 
        gmarkers[i].openInfoWindowHtml(htmls[i]);
 }

       function tohere(i) {
       gmarkers[i].openInfoWindowHtml(to_htmls[i]);
      }
      function fromhere(i) {
        gmarkers[i].openInfoWindowHtml(from_htmls[i]);
      }
}

function load() 
      {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng( -6.801859, 39.282503),
    mapTypeControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
    navigationControl: true,
        zoom: 15,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
    });

    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
    downloadUrl("mapxml.php", function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");

for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++)
   {
    var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
    var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
    var licence_number = markers[i].getAttribute("Licence_number");
    var phone = markers[i].getAttribute("phone");
    var business_image = markers[i].getAttribute("business_image");
    var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
     var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
        parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
        parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));


        //Creating image and get dirrections from point-to-point
        var image_src= '<div class="info-windows img">' + "<img src= '"+ business_image +"'/></div>'";  

        var html ='<div class="info-windows">' + "<b>" +"<h4>Business Name:</h4>"+ name + "</b> <br/>"+"<h4>Address:</h4>" + address + "<br/>"+"<h4>  Licence Number:</h4>" + licence_number + " <br/>" + "<h4>Phone:</h4>" + phone + " <br/>" + image_src  +'<br/>End point address:<form action="http://maps.google.com/maps" method="get"" target="_blank">' + '<br/><input type="text" SIZE=40 MAXLENGTH=40            name="daddr" id="daddr" value="" /><br>' + '<INPUT value="Get Directions" TYPE="SUBMIT">' + '<input type="hidden" name="saddr" value="' + point.lat() + ',' + point.lng() + "(" + name + ")" + '"/></div>';






    var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: point,
      icon: icon.icon,
      shadow: icon.shadow
    });
```

The line var side_bar_html is how I start to create the headings of the display table and afterwards I used the same variable to display the rest of the data.
I need to know how I can paginate them since all of the data is being displayed now.

This is the html where I display the data.

```
 <table width="99%" align="center"   id="product-table" >


                    </table>
```

Comment: Can you please make a jsfiddle out of your code and post, so that it will be easier.

Comment: i cant really do that because most of the data is on localhost

Comment: Have you considered using a [JavaScript framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript_frameworks)?

Comment: try data tables https://datatables.net/ Sorry I havent got the patience to read you whole requirement :)

Comment: Also, why is this question tagged [tag:mysql]?